# how to add and remove event preventDefault method in if else statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs

I'm creating dummy Netflix using node ejs express and mongoose.
I want to add and remove event.preventDefault() method but I don't know how to do it, please help me with something.
This is my app.js signup route.

```
app.get("/signup", (req, res) => {
   Netflix.find({}, function (err, user) {
       res.render("Signup", { email: app.get('data'), Users: user });
   });

});

app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
   const User = new Netflix({
       email: app.get('data'),
       password: req.body.password
   });
   Netflix.findOne({ "email": app.get('data') , "password": req.body.password }, function (err, user) {
       if (err) {
           res.send(err);
       }
       else {
           if (user) {
               res.redirect("/Netflix/Movies");
           }
           else {
               User.save((err) => {
                   if (err) {
                       res.redirect("/signup");
                   }
                   else {
                       res.redirect("/Netflix/Movies");
                   }
               });
           }

       }

   });
});
```

And this is my signup.ejs file and here I write preventDefault() method in else statement but it is still running if that if query will satisfy , How to stop that preventDefault() method from running in if statement.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

            var button = document.getElementById("btn");
            button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
               
                let Users = <%- JSON.stringify(Users) %>;
                console.log("hello");
                Users.forEach(element => {
                    var enteredEmail = <%- JSON.stringify(email) %>;
                    var enteredPassword = document.getElementById("password").value;
                    if (element.email === enteredEmail && element.password === enteredPassword) {
                        document.getElementById("error-text").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("containt").style.marginTop = "0px";
                    }
                    else {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        document.getElementById("error-text").style.display = "inline-flex";
                        document.getElementById("containt").style.marginTop = "100px";
                       
                    }
                });


            });


        </script>
```

Comment: Try using `debugger` statement and check the flow of the code. As per code written above, `event.preventDefault();` will only be triggered id the condition is false. The issue might be something else.

Comment: use return false; at the end of the click handler